# How to differentiate between arrival and departure timings to record in database

Tags: c#, sql

I would really appreciate help to form a logic for the following scenario:

An employee arrives at the organization, swipes his RFID card, gets authenticated and his attendance is marked and the time of arrival is recorded.
at departure, same procedure is repeated.

Currently, I'm using 2 variables i.e. ArrivalTime and DepartureTime to get the values. But, I can't figure out how to tell the system whether the person has arrived or is departing without accessing the database every time.(see if arrival is empty, if yes, its arrival time, else, departure time). I don't want to access db every time though as it will make the system very slow.

Of course, none of these would have been a problem if there were specific timings for arrival and departure, but there are none. I'm making this system for a free clinic where doctors and staffs have different arrivals and departure timings.

@steve: Still haven't thought about that. 1 problem at a time I guess!
@john skeet: Well, I guess about 500 employees. And I'm not sure, but if I access DB a 1000 times to mark attendance, won't it take time to process each attendance? might get stuck at a rush hour, where employees basically swipe and go.
@rene: catering only 1 arrival and 1 departure per employee.
@skeet: seems legit enough!

Comment: How do you plan to handle the missing swipes? I mean when someone forgets to swipe its entrance or exit?

Comment: How often is "every time" and is your database *really* that slow? Given that it's basically a lookup by employee ID, it shouldn't be that slow...

Comment: How many staff do you expect to have an RFID card? How many arrival and departures per staffmember per day?

Comment: Fundamentally, the problem Steve raises is a nasty one that can really only be solved (and then only partially) with heuristics. You may want to consider "what's the maximum time anyone will really be in" for example, as a way of resetting state if you get the wrong way round.

Comment: Please google "premature optimization"

Comment: @JonSkeet being there and it is not a trivial task. A little help comes from the hardware if it could recognize the direction of the swipe. (Left to right for entry and right to left for exit). It is not the definitive solution but with a bit of training for the employees the results are satisfactory. We have also tried the 'maximum time in' but failed short when the employee is really free to enter and exit multiple times in a day/night shift and what counts is just the total hours worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to access the database. End of story. This not a performance issue in the least. Hit the database one time, get all the information you need, store in session for multiple requests to the same page, or store in local storage on the client.

Comment: I have, for example, 500 employees to cater. I'll have to hit the database almost 1000 times then :/ 2 times for each employee

Comment: You are not looking at this problem in the right way, if it is a report or a list you retrieve all 500 employees one time with one request to the database, you get the ArrivalDate and the DepatureDate at the same time with each employee. You are retrieving records for database, the records are rows with columns.

Comment: Retrieving all 500 records at one time, is nothing, not a performance hit in the least.

Comment: Ok, so I retrieve all 500 records at one time, form a data set, check the data set for each employee, and insert attendance at the end of the day for all employee once and for all. Yeap! Problem solved! Thank you! :)